# Swift + JSON -> getting data from url

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am totally new to programming. I passed the autoher_id between two viewcontrollers.

Now I want to list the auther's articles. API url should be :
.../api/author/article/list/(author_id)/(pagenumber)

How am I going to do is in code?

```
var articleList: [JSON]? = []
 var authorid: Int!
 func loadArticle(){
        let url = "http://yazar.io/api/authors/list/" --->>>????
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
            if (json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["artciles"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    self.articleList = data
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Serdar

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
let url = "http://yazar.io/api/authors/list/newspaper/" + String(authorid)
```